# When triaging, the up/down vote is hidden but required

Tags: support, triage

When triaging new questions, I am offered the "Looks OK" option. At the time, the up/down vote is hidden. When clicking "Looks OK", the triage box will shake and tell me I need to upvote if I think it does look OK. The up/down vote now becomes visible. I could not vote at the time, I can only do so after being scolded.

Comment: Voting is not required though. The review queue reminds you that you can vote, but you can skip if you want.

Comment: Does it actually shake? Because yeah, that would definitely look like scolding.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, it shakes for a little while. This is probably because moving things get your attention. Otherwise, you'd probably click the Next button right away.

Comment: The same thing that macOS does to get my attention that I done goofed again and entered the wrong password. Hmm, maybe not the best design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not scolding you for not voting, it's providing you the opportunity to vote now that the review is complete, should you choose to.

Comment: Understood, then I guess this is not a bug so much as an odd UI choice. Shaking UI elements are definitely associated with scolding where I come from.